# Find item where a group the current user is part of is in user column

Tags: caml-query, spsitedataquery

I have multiple lists with the same custom *Person or Group* column `CurrentReviewer` (single selection) which will always contain a `SPGroup`.

I have set up a `SPSiteDataQuery` but I'm missing the last piece of the puzzle in my CAML and that is to identify the groups that the current user is part of.

How can I, using CAML query, find all the rows in a list where a group the current user is a member of appears in the column `CurrentReviewer`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Membership element:

```
<Or>
  <Membership Type=\"CurrentUserGroups\">
    <FieldRef Name=\"AssignedTo\"/>
  </Membership>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name=\"CurrentReviewer\"></FieldRef>
    <Value Type=\"Integer\">
      <UserID/>
    </Value>
  </Eq>
</Or>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa544234(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I came across this before where it didn't work when I tried. Might have been a cache-bummer on my end. Thanks for the answer!